# NodeJS insert video to Youtube playlist

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api

I use NodeJS, I want to insert in my script a function to insert a video to a specific playlist.

I saw a lot on internet, and I know Youtube api requires OAuth to work, and so, some HTML page / callback to get the Token.

Did I miss something or is it impossible to handle this token in script without any user interaction ?

Is there a simple example of how doing this ? I tried this using youtube-api npm :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(),
   Youtube = require("youtube-api"),
   fs = require('fs'),

router.get('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
    Youtube.authenticate({
        type: "oauth"
      , token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZ9F0sVpqEXh"
    });

    var req = Youtube.videos.insert({
        "resource": {
            // Video title and description
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Test",
                "description": "Test video upload via YouTube API"
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        }, 
        "part": "snippet,status,id", 
        "media": {
            "body": fs.createReadStream('./test.mp4')
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(err);

        // insert to playlist
        Youtube.playlistItems.insert({
            "resource": {
                "snippet": {
                    "playlistId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgvjIu",
                    "resourceId": {
                      "kind": "youtube#video",
                      "videoId": data.id // ???
                    }
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": "private"
                }
            }

        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err); 
            }
        });         
    });

    res.json();
});
```

I got error 401 :

> message: 'Login Required'

**EDIT 1**

Good video to start : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc

I got a token now, but don't know how to get no limit no this... Now I changed :

```
Youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth"
  , token: "token_from_google"
});
```

And I got the error :

> message: 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded
>   your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).' } ],
>   code: 403,   message: 'The request cannot be completed because you
>   have exceeded your quota.

I can't understand it ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You have reach the allotted limit ([quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)). See the [Core API errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain) for reference.

> The YouTube Data API uses a quota to ensure that developers use the
>   service as intended and do not create applications that unfairly
>   reduce service quality or limit access for others. All API requests,
>   including invalid requests, incur at least a one-point quota cost. You
>   can find the quota available to your application in the [Developers
>   Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
>
> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of 1 million units per day, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users. Default quota, which is
>   subject to change, helps us optimize quota allocations and scale our
>   infrastructure in a way that is more meaningful to our API users. You
>   can see your quota usage on the [Usage](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/usage) tab for the API in the Google
>   Developer's Console.
>
> *Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota
>   on the [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas) tab in the Developer's Console.*

Comment: What a blast from the past. Back then it was a million, now 10 thousand units per day.